# Why is php file regenerating while uploading via FTP

Tags: php, ftp

I got error file when I tried upload index.php file via FTP which caused destroy my site. Image is attached. Please tell me why? FTP settings: Protocol:FTP, Encryption: usual FTP. I'm using Proxy

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `Transfer type` to `Binary` it helps you.
By default it's Auto